# how to show a modal dialog box on a button click using mobile-angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, mobile-angular-ui

[Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/) Is getting popular which is nothing but bootstrap 3 and angularjs combination

I would like to create a modal dialog box on button click and close the dialog on close icon, how to do it?

Based on the [docs](http://mobileangularui.com/docs/module:mobile-angular-ui/module:components/module:modals/)  it says

```
<div ui-content-for="modals">
    <div class="modal" ui-if="modal1" ui-state='modal1'>
      .....
    </div>
</div>
```

But how to call this dialog, I tried this

```
<button ui-turn-on="modal1" class="btn btn-primary">Show Model</button>
```

But it is not working as expected, I am getting `Warning: Attempt to set uninitialized shared state: modal1`error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have placed `ui-content-for` inside the `ui-yield-to`

Put it outside that `div` tag as follows

```
<div ui-yield-to="modals"></div>
<div ui-content-for="modals">
    <div class="modal" ui-if="modal1" ui-state="modal1">
       ....your model html code
    </div>
</div>
```

So that `modals` will remain as a place holder